# How to center an image in a shiny app?

Tags: r, image, shiny

I am playing with the app:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-plus-three-columns.html

I am inserting a [picture](http://www.bustripping.com/userfiles/images/NFL%20Header.jpg) on the top row by inserting this beneath 'Title'

```
list(img(src="NFL_Header.jpg", width = 400, align = "center")),
```

But it is left justified, the `align` doesn't seem to do anything. How do I specify a center justification for the image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [Yihui](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/555#issuecomment-50572975) himself:

> The align attribute of `<img />` is not what you need. It is a different thing (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp). You can use `style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"` to center an image. Or `div(img(...), style="text-align: center;")`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `HTML` you can place the whole `img` tag in the `center` tag:

```
HTML('<center><img src="NFL_Header.jpg"></center>')
```

[image]

In case the link breaks:

**ui.R**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

    dataset <- diamonds

    shinyUI(fluidPage(

      title = "Diamonds Explorer",

      HTML('<center><img src="NFL_Header.jpg" width="400"></center>'),

      plotOutput('plot'),

      hr(),

      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               h4("Diamonds Explorer"),
               sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', 
                           min=1, max=nrow(dataset),
                           value=min(1000, nrow(dataset)), 
                           step=500, round=0),
               br(),
               checkboxInput('jitter', 'Jitter'),
               checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth')
        ),
        column(4, offset = 1,
               selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
               selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
               selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset)))
        ),
        column(4,
               selectInput('facet_row', 'Facet Row',
                           c(None='.', names(diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.factor)]))),
               selectInput('facet_col', 'Facet Column',
                           c(None='.', names(diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.factor)])))
        )
      )
    ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), input$sampleSize),]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()

    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)

    facets <- paste(input$facet_row, '~', input$facet_col)
    if (facets != '. ~ .')
      p <- p + facet_grid(facets)

    if (input$jitter)
      p <- p + geom_jitter()
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth()

    print(p)

  })

})
```